# Cannot find control panel after installation

Tags: control-panel

After installing craft on apache server, when I try to access control panel using `web/admin`, serwer throws 404 error.
I didnt changed `cpTrigger` setting. Default craft template that displays after installation is displayed correctly.

`.htaccess` file in `web` directory was not modified in any way, its contents are default:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you running nginx? What is your nginx config?

Comment: Apache, just updated my post.

Comment: Does `web/.htaccess` exist on the server?

Comment: Yes, it does, it was not modified in any way. Updated my post.

Comment: What happens if you navigate to `yoururl.com/index.php?p=admin`?

Comment: It redirects to web/admin/login, but error 404 still appears - The requested URL /web/admin/login was not found on this server.

Comment: Ok, then I'm out of ideas regarding /admin. But you have to config your server sir, the amount of information available now is staggering. I can see your licence file, configs, composer.lock files +++. Have the document root set to /web

Comment: Is your Apache config set to AllowOverride for your site?  If not, it won't bother parsing any htaccess files it finds. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Answer (score 1):

Web is the public web folder if you followed the recommended install location, so the link to login is just /admin, i.e.

http://your-domain/admin

Comment: Sorry, i didnt included all info in my post - default craft template that displays after installation is displayed correctly, so url is correct.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me, first time install. Looks pretty neat!